# Service fabric TypeInitializationException during Application Upgrade

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am trying to upgrade the app version for one our SF solutions. But failed multiple times as one of the services is reporting an issue during start with the new version.

Here is what I see as 2 exceptions happening almost at the same time:

```
       OnApply
      Unexpected service exception. Type: System.TypeInitializationException Message: The type initializer for 'MyCompany.MyService.Interfaces.Models.MyUser' threw an exception. HResult: 0x80131534
      Log record. Type: BeginTransaction LSN: 103498
   at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.OnApplyAdd(TransactionBase txn, MetadataOperationData metadataOperationData, RedoUndoOperationData operationRedoUndo, Boolean isIdempotent, String applyType)
   at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.<OnRecoveryApplyAsync>d__299.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.<Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Replicator-IStateProvider2-ApplyAsync>d__237.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.<OnApplyAsync>d__106.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.<OnApplyAsync>d__105.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.OperationProcessor.<ApplyCallback>d__36.MoveNext().
```

And

```
Exception in OpenAsync.  Type: System.TypeInitializationException Message: The type initializer for 'MyCompany.MyService.Interfaces.Models.MyUser' threw an exception. HResult: 0x80131534. Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.RecoveryManager.<PerformRecoveryAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LoggingReplicator.<PerformRecoveryAsync>d__137.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.DynamicStateManager.<OpenAsync>d__109.MoveNext().
```

I would expect to see this kind of error in case any changes happened to the "MyUser" model, but it was not changed at all.

Not sure if it has to do with some kind of an issue with the SF version we are using: 5.7.198 as this is not the latest one.

Anyone faced something similar or have good ideas for a work around?

P.S. This is a production system with real customers. Being able to make upgrades and not loosing their data is a must. Hence re-creation of the SF/cluster is not an option.

Comment: Make sure that the SDK used to build the application, fits with the cluster version. Runtime: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/E/29E129A2-5C20-46A6-83EB-A4958097DC2E/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.7.198.9494.exe
SDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/E/29E129A2-5C20-46A6-83EB-A4958097DC2E/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.7.198.msi 
Visual Studio 2015: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/E/29E129A2-5C20-46A6-83EB-A4958097DC2E/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi

Comment: It definitely fits. I even have set the cluster to Manual upgrade after we made the app available for customers. My idea back then was to prevent exactly such cases...

Comment: Ok, probably best to make a support case then.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and they told me that this kind of error is most likely caused by development issue (i.e. nothing to do with their infrastructure) and they can't do much about it.

Comment: Can you share the code of the type initializer of the class `MyCompany.MyService.Interfaces.Models.MyUser` ?

Comment: Sure, I've shared it [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/471d7e7e43c1f8c5635d210b0a1138f6)

Comment: It might be related to the immutable collection, as that is the only initialized static member. Can you try it without using immutable list, to see if that is where the issue originates?

Comment: LoekD, thanks for the involvement so far! :). I continued to analyze the case and got to a bug in a method in one of our services (using the MyUser model) which opened a transaction outside of a loop and committed inside the loop. This method was periodically called in the service triggered by the RunAsync... Still have doubts that this could have caused the above error, but the upgrade just went all the way through all domains.

Comment: thanks for the update!